# PY4J with generics

Tags: python, scala, jvm, py4j

With the following class definition:

```
class MyClass[T : ClassTag]{
  def this(stuff : T){
    // ....
  }
}
```

PY4J will throw the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.MyClass. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor MyClass([class java.lang.String]) does not exist
```

If you try to instantiate with:

```
myObject = _gateway.jvm.MyClass("string")
```

I do use reflection somewhere else in my code to search for the default constructor, but that has a signature of `(java.lang.Object, scala.reflection.ClassTag)`. I don't think that PY4J tries to find it correctly. I do know, that it uses reflection heavily, but maybe it is not prepared for use cases like this.

Or is there any workaround to successfully instantiate a generic class like this?

Comment: Py4J does usually work ok with generics because it works with Collections. It is possible though that it is thrown off by the ClassTag or the new def keyword. Please open an issue on the bug tracker, ideally with a full example (I don't have much experience with Scala): https://github.com/bartdag/py4j/issues

Comment: The only alternative for now would be to write a shim in Java/Scala that does the instantiation on the Java side.